# Add list to another one - nested list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, list, nested-lists

I would like to add some list to another list.

The result should looks like a main list contains nested list elements.

```
MainList:
 [0]InnerList:
    [0]some values
    [1]some values
 [1]InnerList:
    [0]some values
    [1]some values
```

I try to do this this way:

```
list.Add(new List<myClass>().Add(innerList));
```

but I've got an error message

Comment: How is your root list defined? What is the error message?

Comment: Check `AddRange` method: `list.AddRange(otherList);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it up, add does not return the list.

```
List<List<String>> inner = new List<List<String>>();
List<String> leaves = new List<String>();

leaves.Add( "some string" );
inner.Add( leaves );
list.Add( inner );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the list constructor instead of the `Add` method. Because the `Add` method returns void.

```
list.Add(new List<myClass>(innerList));
```

or if `innerList` is already of type `List<myClass>` then you can do:

```
list.Add(innerList);
```

Answer (score 0):

List of elements of type `myClass` is `List<myClass>` so list of such lists is `List<List<myClass>>`. Here is a simple example how to create and populate such list of lists in one line (I used fictional type `C`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<List<C>>{
            new List<C>{
                new C(1), 
                new C(2)
            }, 
            new List<C>{
                new C(3), 
                new C(4)
            }
        };


        Console.WriteLine((list[0][0]).Value);
        Console.WriteLine((list[0][1]).Value);
        Console.WriteLine((list[1][0]).Value);
        Console.WriteLine((list[1][1]).Value);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public int Value;

    public C(int val)
    {
        this.Value = val;
    }
}
```

This will give you output:

```
1
2
3
4
```